# What is the difference between WebRTC, Jingle and XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, webrtc, voip, jingle

What's the difference between WebRTC and Jingle. I am going to build Android based voice calling app using XMPP ejabberd server. So, which one of these will be best choice for voice calling on Android?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

XMPP is a messaging protocol. Jingle the subprotocol that XMPP uses for establishing voice-over-ip calls or transfer files. WebRTC is a Javascript API (there is also a library implementing that API).

You can use Jingle as a signaling protocol to establish a peer-to-perconnection between two XMPP clients using the WebRTC API. [This](https://github.com/legastero/jingle-interop-demos) shows an example in Javascript that works in Chrome and Firefox (and Microsoft Edge if you only want audio).

Comment: so you mean to say ... WebRTC APIs uses XMPP for messaging and Jingle for SIgnaling ?

Comment: no. WebRTC doesn't define signaling, only an API. You can use Jingle or anything else, see [here](https://bloggeek.me/siganling-protocol-webrtc/) for a more detailed discussion

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC code in [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/) only contains the video and audio codec, the RTP stack. The libjingle project contains the API of webRTC, it looks nurse but it's true. Besides, the libjingle has the stacks of XMPP and STUN, ICE implementation. If you want to make a total solution for VOIP, you have to build both.